# Purchase item final total how to calculate

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have created a purchase report of inventory control system. If we want to check the purchase select from the date and to date check how to item we purchased. all record will display on dataTable successfully but my problem is there is column {"sTitle": "total", "mData": "total"} here I need to calculate the final amount of the purchase every day.it will display below the data table. 
Total amount of purchased.

```
function get_all() {
                    var from_date = $('#from_date').val();
                    var to_date = $('#to_date').val();
                    $('#tbl-projects').dataTable().fnDestroy();

                    $.ajax({
                        url:"all_purchase.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        data:{from_date:from_date, to_date:to_date},
                        async:false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);

                            $('#tbl-projects').dataTable({
                                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                                buttons: [
                                    , 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                                ],

                                "aaData": data
                                ,
                                "scrollX": true,
                                "aoColumns": [
                                    {"sTitle": "Invoice No", "mData": "Invoice_id"},
                                    {"sTitle": "VendorName", "mData": "vendor_id"},
                                    {"sTitle": "date", "mData": "date"},
                                    {"sTitle": "total", "mData": "total"},
                                    {"sTitle": "pay", "mData": "pay"},
                                    {"sTitle": "due", "mData": "due"},
                                    {"sTitle": "payment_type", "mData": "payment_type"},
                                    {
                                        "sTitle": "Payment Status","mData": "due", "render": function (mData, type, row, meta) {
                                        if (mData != 0) {
                                            return '<span class="label label-info">Pending</span>';
                                        }
                                        else  {
                                            return '<span class="label label-warning">Complete</span>';
                                        }
                                    }
                                    },
                                  ]
                            });
                        },
                        error: function (xhr) {
                            console.log('Request Status: ' + xhr.status  );
                            console.log('Status Text: ' + xhr.statusText );
                            console.log(xhr.responseText);
                            var text = $($.parseHTML(xhr.responseText)).filter('.trace-message').text();
                            console.log(text)
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Comment: Try like this https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html

Comment: yes i studied but i am Loading the data from database

Comment: all data displayed successfully how to callculate the final total